# Newbie with Conda ,Celery ,Python

Tags: python, flask

I need to do a setup of below softwares on Windows:

- Anaconda-mini
- Celery
- Flask
- Mongo
- RabbitMQ

I was able to download all of them, but when I try to run below command I get an error.

```
conda env create -f conda.yml

(base) C:\TunningPortal\portalApp>conda env create -f conda.yml
WARNING: A space was detected in your requested environment path
'C:\Users\XXX XXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\runapp'
Spaces in paths can sometimes be problematic.
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - ptyprocess
  - libcxx
  - libffi
```

How to resolve above error?

Comment: What are the contents of your conda.yml file?

Comment: dependencies:
  - appnope
  - backcall
  - ca-certificates
  - certifi
  - decorator
  - ipython
  - ipython_genutils
  - jedi
  - libcxx
  - libcxxabi
  - libedit
  - libffi
  - ncurses
  - openssl
  - parso
  - pexpect
  - pickleshare
  - pip
  - prompt_toolkit
  - ptyprocess
  - pygments
  - pymongo
  - python
  - readline
  - setuptools
  - simplegeneric
  - six
  - sqlite
  - tk
  - traitlets
  - wcwidth
  - wheel
  - xz
  - zlib

Comment: - pip:
    - amqp
    - aniso8601
    - billiard
    - celery=4.2.1
    - click
    - dominate
    - flask
    - flask-bootstrap
    - flask-restful
    - itsdangerous
    - jinja2
    - kombu
    - markupsafe
    - pytz
    - vine
    - visitor
    - werkzeug